# Generate a pdf from multiple views using Rotativa?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rotativa

I want to generate a single pdf using 2 views. My target is to generate the first page from the first View and the seconnd page from the second view.

This is my current code:

```
var actionPDF = new Rotativa.ActionAsPdf("DownloadDividendSummaryPdf", new { ReportType = DividendType, Time = DividendTime })
                {
                    FileName = "DividendPortfolio" + email + ".pdf",
                    PageSize = Size.A4,
                    MinimumFontSize = 12,
                    //PageMargins = new Margins(3, 3, 3, 3),
                    IsGrayScale = true,
                    IsJavaScriptDisabled = true,
                    IsBackgroundDisabled = true,
                };

                actionPDF = new Rotativa.ActionAsPdf("DownloadDividendDetailedPdf", new { ReportType = DividendType, Time = DividendTime, StartDate = G_StartDate, todate = G_ToDate })
                {
                    FileName = "DividendPortfolio" + email + ".pdf",
                    PageSize = Size.A4,
                    MinimumFontSize = 12,
                    //PageMargins = new Margins(3, 3, 3, 3),
                    IsGrayScale = true,
                    IsJavaScriptDisabled = true,
                    IsBackgroundDisabled = true,
                };
```

Answer (score 0):

Either merge the PDFs (not trivial), or simply create a view that renders the output of both other views, then render *that* view to a PDF.

Comment: I am using header html for each view. Then how can I create a view that renders both?

Comment: My situation is explaned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69795806/how-to-generate-a-single-pdf-using-rotativa-from-a-view-which-has-different-dyna)

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine the generated byte arrays into one.

Here is the simplifed set up:

```
        //Create single views
        ViewAsPdf view = new ViewAsPdf("ViewName", viewModel);
        byte[] viewData = view.BuildFile(ControllerContext);

        //Add them to array
        List<byte[]> viewDatas = new List<byte[]>();
        viewDatas.Add(viewData);

        //Combine them
        byte[] combinedViewData = combineViewData(viewDatas);
```

Here is the combineViewData helper method:

```
    private static byte[] combineViewData(List<byte[]> viewData)
    {
        byte[] combinedViewData = null;

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (Document document = new Document())
            {
                using (PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, ms))
                {
                    document.Open();

                    foreach (byte[] arr in viewData)
                    {
                        using (MemoryStream viewStream = new MemoryStream(arr))
                        {
                            using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(viewStream))
                            {
                                int n = reader.NumberOfPages;
                                for (int page = 0; page < n;)
                                {
                                    copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(reader, ++page));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            combinedViewData = ms.ToArray();
        }
        return combinedViewData;
    }
```

Comment: `PDFCopy` is that Rotativa?

Comment: `PDFCopy` is for iTextSharp